# 63 vulnerabilities found - Creating react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to create a react app but it gives me 63 vulnerabilities, I am a new user of react and if someone experienced can help me setup my project that would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
iMacbook-Pro:can-game sam$. create-react-app can-game

//...

react-dom@16.8.4
added 1974 packages from 735 contributors and audited 36232 packages in 54.031s
found 63 low severity vulnerabilities
run npm audit fix to fix them, or npm audit for details
// ...

iMacbook-Pro:Desktop sam$ npm audit fix
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOPJSON
npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/sam/.npm/_logs/2019-03-14T04_59_30_573Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You can see get specifics on what the issue with `npm audit`. I probably won't pay too much mind to low severity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the output of `npm audit fix`, it appears that your current directory does not include a `package.json`.

You probably need to change directories to the one that `create-react-app can-game` just created for you. You can do this using `cd can-game`.

Once this is done, run `npm audit fix` again and it should look for vulnerability issues successfully.

On a side note: like the output told you, these are low severity issues so you should be pretty safe even without running `npm audit fix`.

Comment: iMacbook-Pro:can-game sam$ npm audit fix
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.0.1 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

up to date in 7.848s
fixed 0 of 63 vulnerabilities in 36232 scanned packages
  63 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
iMacbook-Pro:can-game sam$

Comment: Also when I try to save the bootstrapiMacbook-Pro:can-game sam$ npm install --save bootstrap
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.0.1 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ bootstrap@4.3.1
added 1 package from 2 contributors and audited 36237 packages in 13.814s
found 63 low severity

Comment: I installed the dependencies and it works now, thanks for directing me right path.

Comment: No problem. If this solved your problem please consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

These vulnerabilities found maybe because of your node version. Even then this is `devdependency`. Wouldn't affect your production build.